# Modifying PHP code of an Include, outside of the include?

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to set a PHP variable: `$custom`, that will be used whenever it is defined.

But I want the output of this variable to be dependant of another variable: `$v` index, which is used inside `while`, which gets defined only during the `while` statement.

I don't know if it's possible to do, right now I have the following code, and for the way I defined `$custom[3]`, it doesn't work.

Only `$custom[1]` and `$custom[2]` varibables will work, but they take into account only constant values or variable whose values were already set, so this isn't helpful.

Code:

```
<?php

$product[1]["price"]=10;
$product[2]["price"]=50;
$product[3]["price"]=70;

$custom[1] = 'Static HTML Block';
$custom[2] = 'Past Variable: '. $product[2]["price"] .'';
$custom[3] = 'Future Variable: '. $product[$v]["price"] .''; // I want this kind of definitoin

?>

<HTML>

// the following part will be used within an include, and shouldn't be modified ///

<?php 

$v = 1; 

while ($z <= 5) { 

?>

<?= $custom[$v] ? $custom[$v] : '$' . $product[$v]["price"] ?>

<?php 

$v = $v + 1;
$z = $z + 1;

} 

?>
```

So basically, I want that on the third run (when `v=3`), that `Future Variable: 70` will be the output.

**The Rationale:**

I want to use the latter code as a constant `Include`, that will serve as a template for all files. but on occasion, a certain file may require special changes that also require PHP code modification, so I will want to perform them within such specific file, that will affect the original `include`.

Edit 2:

More Simple example:

```
<?php

$product[1]["price"]=10;
$product[2]["price"]=50;

$custom[1] = 'I dont modify the PHP code';
$custom[2] = 'I DO mofiy the latter PHP code: '. $product[$v]["price"] .'';
?>

<HTML>

// the following part will be used within an include, and shouldn't be modified ///

<?php $v = 1; while ($v <= 5) { ?>

<?= $custom[$v] ?>
<p>

<?php $v = $v + 1; } ?>

// Expected Output:

//I dont modify the PHP code
//I DO mofiy the latter PHP code: 50
```

Comment: where's `$i` in your code? can you clarify your question?

Comment: @Federico sorry, meant `$v`, edited.

Comment: As stated in the answers below you're after a template language/framework. You can either use existing OTS solutions such as twig, or you can use preg_replace in a separate function. You need to properly define your requirements and expected output/outcome before anyone can properly assist you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, but if I had to guess, you want something known as *templates* (e.g. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)), and your question might possibly be a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you supply more context maybe someone might be able to help you further.

As to the matter at hand, you cannot define `$custom[3]` here since $v is not defined yet:

```
$custom[3] = 'Future Variable: '. $product[$v]["price"] .''; // I want this kind of definitoin
```

The closest you can get is to use `eval` (which is rarely recommended), or define a *closure*, even if it's awkward. Instead of a variable, you define a *function*:

```
$custom[3] = function($productData) {
    return 'Future Variable: '. $productData["price"] .'';
}
```

The above you can do in an included file.

Then in the loop you check whether the custom object is a function, and if so, you call it and assign the return value to the reply.

The code below stays the same whatever the include - actually, it even works with the data you have now. Of course, it has to be a little more complicated.

```
while ($z <= 5) { 

    // If the $v-th item is customised
    if (array_key_exists($v, $custom)) {
        // Verify what it is
        if (is_callable($custom[$v])) {
            // if it's a function, call it.
            $reply = $custom[$v]($product);
        } else {
            $reply = $custom[$v];
        }
    } else {
        // Not customised, just print the price.
        $reply = '$' . $product[$v]["price"];
    }
    print $reply;
```

Another more "templateish" solution is to define strings and then process them using e.g. `preg_replace_callback` in order to generate the desired HTML. In this case, too, you need to pass to the templater a fixed variable, such as `$product[$v]`. You need some kind of 'language' to indicate where you want elements of this fixed variables to be instantiated. Usually, square brackets or curly brackets, often doubled, are used:

```
$custom[3] = 'Future Variable: {{price}}';
```

At resolution time, `preg_replace_callback` may be made to replace {{price}} with the value in `$product[$v]['price']`, and so on (e.g. {{weight}}, {{description}}...).

(You can also do this server side and populate the HTML page via AJAX using client-side libraries such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)).

Comment: Please see my the rational I've just added to my question. I don't want a solution that involves changing the  `while`, as I want to use that piece of code as an include.

Comment: @rockyraw: FYI it's "rationale" (fifth time I've corrected that on SO today; what is going on?!)

Comment: You would actually change the `while` only once, then you'd go on by only changing `$custom`. I can't quite see a way for the `while` as it is *now* to be made to work with a "future" definition of `$v`. I think that you could get everything you need now with a minimal templating using `preg_replace_callback`, though.

Comment: @lserni I know what I want, not what I need, because what I may need is not something I can answer at present time. That's the idea with this code being a template - In the future, it might arise that some modifications may be needed for particular pages, and thus I rather have an ability to preserve the original template, and make those PHP modifications directly from the specific page, using the upper piece of code...

Comment: You're definitely after templating. To use functions, as above, is perhaps the faster solution that will get you the most mileage (*not* the best solution, mind; *that* would be investing some time to integrate Twig, or any real templating engine). I've updated the answer to better show how to do this with an include + while loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to tell what you are trying to do, but I think you need to decouple your data from your presentation:

```
$product[1]['price']=10;
$product[2]['price']=50;
$product[3]['price']=70;

$custom[1] = 'Static HTML Block';
$custom[2] = 'Past Variable: %s';
$custom[3] = 'Future Variable: %s';

$v = 1;
while($z <= 5) {
    $price = $product[ $v ]['price'];
    printf($custom[ $v ], $price);
    $v++;
    $z++;
}
```

In this case, `$custom` stores the *format*, but doesn't actually contain the data. You call `printf` to output the desired format with whatever data you want to pass.

Comment: I don't want simply a format, I want to have the flexibility to change the latter PHP code by changing the former PHP code. **The Rational:** I want to use the latter code as a constant `Include`, that will serve as a template for all files. but on occassion, a certain file may require special changes that also have to do with PHP code modification, so I will want to peform them from such specific file, while keeping the original `include`.

Comment: @rockyraw Sorry, I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to accomplish. I think your example may be too general. Can you provide anything more specific?

Comment: Overall, I'm just looking for a general way to modify PHP content of an `include`. the code in my question is just a specific example for how I wish to utilize such way.

Comment: Edited question with a more simple example.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and nasty way to make your own template is to create an array of keys => values and pass it to the where loops as your `$custom` variable.

While you're in the `where(){}` loop, use the php function `extract` to convert the array into `$key = 'value'` pairs. This is very similar to `list` without having having to define each variable manually.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Eg.

```
$data = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
];

extract($data);
print $foo; // output: bar
```

Then after you extract, include your file. Make sure that you wrap this in output buffering mode `ob_start()` and put it in a function so your local variables can't be overriden.

This is how you make homebrew templating languages.